# how to take screenshot and disable flag_secure

Tags: root-access, screenshots, android-11

I am kind of surprised that there seems to be no clear way to do this.  I have a rooted pixel 4 with android 11. I can't pass ctsProfile but it is rooted.

I have also tried to use Taichi apk to create an app with disable flag_secure but the newly crated apk does not work.

Please can anyone show me how to disable flag_secure exactly? I did not know it is this annoying even after rooting.

Comment: A simple workaround even for non-rooted devices is to enable adb, connect your phone to a PC and use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror the phone screen to your desktop. This works even for apps that use flag_secure and on the PC you can simply make a screen-shot of the scrcpy window.

Comment: Did you try this: https://repo.xposed.info/module/fi.veetipaananen.android.disableflagsecure? It worked for me when I used it last time. Not sure on Android 9 or 10.